# How to detect a browser screen width increase past a certain point using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

basically, what I want to do is trigger an event if the user increases the size of the browser from X to Y. Provided X = Anything less than 750 pixels, and Y is anything more than 750 pixels.

Right now, I am doing something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() >= 750) {
        console.log('750 or more');
    }
});
```

This works, however, its clearly not efficient. For example, if I resize my window from 780px to max width (1024px), even then the event gets triggered. Or even if I decrease the size from 800px to 780px, I still obviously get the console output.

How do I get this to work right?

Comment: Depending on the action you want to do when the browser window is resized, you may want to look at using CSS media queries.

Comment: Those are out the question here, because I want to change an attribute of a DOM element when the size changes.

Comment: In that case your code is the only option you have. I would suggest you look at debouncing the event handler though, as it will fire once for every pixel the screen width gets updated by.

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to build a responsive nav-bar from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to **setTimeout** to allow check to take place .

**Example :**

```
var resizeTimer;

$(window).resize(function() {


 clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    var body_size = $(window).width();

    // ...
    // do your screen check here
    // ...


  }, 1);

})
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There's no true solution for this issue since removing the on resize event after max width has been reached results in the on resize function no longer being called even when the width is below 1024px.

Maybe in the future it's possible to have an on resize event under certain conditions only.

You can also use the on resize end event to only trigger the function after resizing the window, keep in mind this might result in visual changes happening after a user has resized a window instead of during the resizing of a window.

There are multiple methods to make the on resize event perform better: http://bencentra.com/code/2015/02/27/optimizing-window-resize.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a throttled version using script that might be a good start

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/68125jkm/3/)

```js
(function(timeout,bigger) {     // local static var - timeout,bigger

      window.addEventListener("resize", function(e) {
        if ( !timeout ) {
          timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            timeout = null;
            actualResizeHandler(e);

            // Set the actual fire rate
          }, 66);
        }
      }, false);

      function actualResizeHandler(e) {
        // handle the resize event
        
        if (window.innerWidth >= 750 && !bigger) {
          //passed above (or equal) 750
          document.querySelector('span').style.color = 'blue';
          document.body.innerHTML += '<br>above 750';
          
        } else if (window.innerWidth < 750 && bigger) {
          //passed below 750
          document.querySelector('span').style.color = 'red';
          document.body.innerHTML += '<br>below 750';
        }
        bigger = (window.innerWidth >= 750);

      }
      
      // run once at load
      bigger = (window.innerWidth < 750);
      actualResizeHandler();
    
    }(null,false));
```

```html
<span>This text is blue on big and red on small</span>
```

and here is one use CSS media query

```css
span {
  color: red;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  span {
    color: blue
  }  
}
```

```html
<span>This text is blue on big and red on small</span>
```